# <p> Box is really big and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, paragraph

[image]

Why is the box on my paragraph tag really big? I think this may be the reason why I can't push the `<p>` tag down with `margin-top: 50px;`

```css
.train p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="train">
  <p class="train">In Training</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by really big? What is your intended output?

Comment: I don't see how the code posted relates to your image. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag is a block element. Block level elements, regardless of their width, take an entire line to themselves within their parent. try wrapping a span around the piece that you want to style

Answer (score 0):

A simple example for you to see the problem (also a good way to debug HTML/CSS). `<p>` and `<div>` those are by default `block level` elements

> [image]
>
> Strongly suggest you to taking 3 mins to read the following link
>
> #### REF: http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

```css
p.train {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="train">In Training</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

## Solution:

Set `p` to inline-block

#### or

just use a `span` which is an inline element:

```css
p.train {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.green {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="train">In Training</p>
  <hr>
  <span class="green">In Training</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Display: inlineblock; fixed it

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy check the updated answer for detail example of the difference between block/inline/inline-block, if this solved your problem, please accept the answer. thanks =D